# How to get 2 videos (that belongs to a program and program belogns to a category) for every category?

Tags: mysql

There 3 tables category, program, video. Every video belongs to a program, and any program belongs to a category.

**Category  table**

```
id | title
1  | cartoons
2  | documental
```

**Program table**

```
id | programcode | title         | category_id
1  | WUCU        | Program Name  | 1
2  | ELKI        | Program Name  | 2
```

**Video table**

```
id | videocode | title | program_id
1  | ELKI00001 | Name  | 2
2  | ELKI00002 | Name  | 2
3  | ELKI00003 | Name  | 2
4  | WUCU00001 | Name  | 1
5  | WUCU00002 | Name  | 1
6  | WUCU00003 | Name  | 1
```

I need to get last 2 videos  for every category

Comment: what determines "Last"? those videos with the highest ID in each category?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @xQbert yes highest ID

Comment: @StrawBerry here is the sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ad8c6

Comment: @surgun9 Why are you telling me this? Also, the data set in the question and the fiddle are different. This is confusing.

Comment: @Strawberry if you had a nickel for every time you've used that comment "provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2..... " you'd be filthy rich! lol.. its amazing how many posts are on here with next to no data :)

Comment: Well, a dime maybe ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: MySQL doesn't support getting the top most N values in a group.  So we have to do it ourselves.  This means we need a way to group the sets together (Category.Title and a way to know which videos to return belonging to each category.  We'd like to use LIMIT here to limit the results by 2 but we can't limit by 2 for each category.  We'd also like to use MAX to get the highest video ID for each category but that doesn't get us the 2nd one.  So we have to build those in ourselves.

This is built using logic found:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

but altered to fit your data set

This is working but I don't know why I'm having to do multiple subselects for @RNUM and @VCAT.  Not sure why they have to be separated at this point.  [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ad8c6/47/1)

```
set @Rnum :=0, @VCat :='';

SELECT * FROM (
Select SequencedSet.*, @Rnum := if(mvcat = CTitle, @Rnum + 1, 1) RowNumber from (
SELECT CTitle, VCode, VTitle, VID, @vcat mvcat,
  @VCat := CTitle  as VCAT
  FROM (
SELECT C.Title CTitle, V.Code VCode, V.Title VTitle, V.ID VID
FROM Video V
INNER JOIN Program P
  on P.ID = V.Program_Id
INNER JOIN Category C
  on C.ID = P.Category_ID
ORDER BY C.Title, V.ID DESC) orderedset) sequencedSet) X
where X.ROWNUMBER<=2
```

Comment: Altered to remove extra ) in original post and refactor a bit.

Comment: should have been @vcat=ctitle;  the intent here was to validate the row in question is of the same type as the prior row, otherwise restart numbering.

Comment: Got all videos from the video table not only 2 by category
here is the sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ad8c6

Comment: I got it working but I don't know why I have to do an added step...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ad8c6/47/1  all I can think is that I have a scoping problem with variable use which is causing me to have to derive the inline view first....

Comment: Haven't studied, but 'feels' like too much answer here

Comment: Minimized to "answer" but I still don't' like it as I don't know why I have to have so many subselects.